# Codebehind method doesn't fire even after javascript function returns true

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a javascript function in my webform as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteNodeAssets() {
        var isdeletable = document.getElementById("<%=hdisDeletable.ClientID %>").value;
        if (isdeletable == "False") {
            alert("This item can't be deleted!");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            var treeView = $find("<%=tvAssets.ClientID%>");
            var allNodes = treeView.get_allNodes();
            if (allNodes.length < 1) {
                alert("The treeview is empty.");
                return false;
            }

            var selectedNode = treeView.get_selectedNode();
            if (!selectedNode) {
                alert("You need to select an item first.");
                return false;
            }
            var childs = selectedNode.get_childListElement();
            if (childs != null || childs == "") {
                if (!confirm("This item contains sub-groups. Are you sure you want to delete all related items?"))
                    return false;
            }

            if (allNodes.length == 1) {
                if (!confirm("This is the last item in the treeview. Are you sure you want to delete it?"))
                    return false;
            }

            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the item?")) {
                return true;
            }   
        }
    }
</script>
```

Which is fired during click on Remove button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRemoveNodeAssets" runat="server"  OnClientClick="return deleteNodeAssets();"
                                Text="Remove Item" OnClick="btnRemoveNodeAssets_Click" />
```

Problem I am facing is that even if the `deleteNodeAssets()` returns `true` my codebehind method `btnRemoveNodeAssets_Click` doesn't fire at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net button is not a submit type button.

After generation button will be `<input type="button" />`

If your method return a value in `OnClientClick` then `onClick` won't trigger.

So if your method return false then return value

if reutrn false then do nothing then onClick will be called

Try like this

```
OnClientClick="if(!deleteNodeAssets()) return false;"
```

Comment: It works... Thnx.. If you don't mind can you explain why did it work.. I didn't understand last 2 lines  'So if your method return false then return value  if reutrn false then do nothing then onClick will be called'.

Comment: if you attach client click handler of such a button that returns a value it will prevent execution of the script that are attached after your code

Comment: then return only when validation is false

Comment: Do you mean to say "it will prevent execution of the code that are attached after the script"?